# Distance between vectors multiplied by scalars

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose that $x,y$ are some vectors in a Euclidean space and $a,b$ are some scalars. Is there any inequality to factor out $||x-y||$ from

$$||a x - b y || $$

like this:

$$ ||a x - b y || \leq ||x-y|| \cdot \text{something} $$

?

What if the metric is $d_{\infty}$? Namely if:

$$ ||x-y|| = \max_i |x^i - y^i | $$

where $x^i$ is just the $i-$th coordinate of $x$.

Comment: By $d_\infty$ you mean that you are working with bounded sequences and $\|x-y\|=\sup |x_n-y_n|$? (I don't think it will change anything, but this information seems to be missing in your post.)

Comment: Valery: Maybe it would be reasonable adding such information to the post.

Comment: This is kind of trivial, so I assume this is not what you're looking for: $\|ax-by\| = \|a(x-y)+(a-b)y\| \le |a| \|x-y\| + |a-b|\cdot\|y\| = \left(|a|+|a-b|\cdot\frac{\|y\|}{\|x-y\|}\right)\|x-y\|$. (On the other hand, if you have some estimate on $\frac{\|y\|}{\|x-y\|}$ in the situation where you want apply the inequality you're asking for, this would gives you at least something.)

Comment: Valery: I have noticed that in the meantime. (I noticed that post among linked question and I have also noticed [your comment there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495341/generalization-of-piece-wise-linear-functions-over-a-metric-space#comment3048455_1495534).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's trivial to have $x-y=0$ and $|| ax-by||>0$ no such bound can be obtained.