# Extending to a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $A, B \subset X$ be two open sets such that $d(A, B) \geq 1$. Suppose we have a function $f$ defined only on $A \cup B$ such that $f|_A \equiv 1$ and $f|_B \equiv -1$. My question is, can we extend $f$ as a Lipschitz function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the Lipschitz norm of $f$ is $\leq 2$?

My intuitive guess is that the answer is yes, and $f$ could be defined in terms of some convenient distance function, but I cannot quite put my finger on it. I am also unsure whether $X$ needs to be compact for this to happen. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac {d(x,B)-d(x,A)} {d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$ is Lipschitz, $1$ on $A$ and $-1$ in $B$ but I am not sure if the Lipschitz constant is at most $2$. Try to work out the constant.

Comment: [This might help.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926124/urysohns-lemma-with-lipschitz-functions)

Comment: This is excellent, truly nothing new under the sun! But of course,  KaviRamaMurthy's solution was also working (essentially a variant of the one you gave).