# infinitely small vs arbitrarily small

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

In a question I recently asked, [Definitions of supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109248/definitions-of-supremum/2109262?noredirect=1#comment4337650_2109262) it was pointed out that my usage of infinitly small was misguided, and the proper terminology was arbitrarily small. Could someone explain what is the difference between the two? Say in a context such as: take some $\epsilon$ infinitely small/arbitrary.

Comment: well, what does infinitely small mean?

Comment: 0? or some value that tends to 0?

Comment: What does "value that tends to 0" mean? Can you give an example of a value that tends to 0?

Comment: "Arbitrarily small" is not a condition on a number. It's an implicit quantifier on what you're about to say.

Comment: When you declare $\epsilon$ to be infinitely small, you have assigned it a value already. When you say "let $\epsilon$ be arbitrarily small", it us up to the reader to choose a value for $\epsilon$. The latter definition is taken when you must prove something for any possible value.

Comment: Yes, the question from @Ittay Weiss makes me realise the inaccurate description of infinitely small. When arbitrarily small does not take some fixed value. I think i understand why we use the term arbitrary.

Comment: The infinite is not a quantity in the reals, but when you says "$\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small" you are talking of quantities in the positive reals.