# Compactess of the sum closed balls whose centers is a compact set.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(\mathcal{X},d) $ be a compact and metric space and let $A \subset \mathcal{X}$ be a compact subset and let $\alpha >0 $. Consider the set 
$$
C(A, \alpha) = \{ x \in \mathcal{X }\,  | \, d(x,A) \leq \alpha\}
$$
How to prove or disprove that $C(A, \alpha) $ is compact?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $C(A,\alpha)$ is closed because the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}\Delta\colon&\mathcal{X}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&a&\mapsto&d(a,A)\end{array}$$[is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944659/distance-to-a-closed-set-is-continuous) and $C(A,\alpha)=\Delta^{-1}\bigl([0,\alpha]\bigr)$.

Now, use the fact that a closed subset of a compact metric space is always compact.

Comment: Dear @José Carlos Santos ,Why $C(A,\alpha)$ is closed?. So far I know $C(A,\alpha)$ is an uncontable sum of closed balls. But any uncontable sum of closed balls not necessary it closed.

Comment: @jaogye I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: Dear @José Carlos Santos many thanks for answer.

Comment: @jaogye I'm glad I could help.