# Can we construct a function in the following way on $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

> Show that, for any $0<r<R$, there exists a function $\phi\colon\mathbb R^n\to[0,1]$ such that $$\phi(x):=
>   \begin{cases}
>     1 & \text{when }x\in B(x,r), \\
>     0 & \text{when }x\in B(x,R)^c.
>   \end{cases}$$ where recall that $B(x,r)=\{y\in\mathbb R^n; |y-x|<r\}$.

**My Attempt:** I found this  problem so trivial. We can always find a function $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} 1 , x \in B(x,r) \\ 0 , x \in B(x,R)^c \\ \frac{1}{2} 
 \text{otherwise }\end{cases}$

Is there any twist ? Can anyone please tell  me ?

Comment: Surprising that, in a topology context, you are not providing a continuous function (in the standard topologies of the spaces in question).

Comment: $x\in B(x,r)$ is a true statement so $\phi(x)\equiv1$, unless it is a typo. In that case I also believe that the question wanted some specific kind of function (like continuous function) mention of which has not been made.

Comment: Is my attempt okay given the question is right ?@EricTowers

Comment: I was given this question only. Can you please tell me if my attempt is correct ?@ShubhamJohri

Comment: I find this question weird. That is why I posted this question here.@EricTowers

Comment: A more general Q&A: [Urysohn's function on a metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47360).

Answer (score 4):

The question is at stands makes no sense at all, there is a weird double use of $x$ here (it must be the centre of some fixed balls $B(x,r), B(x,R)$ but it's also used as a variable. Moreover, of course this function must be at least *continuous* (maybe even smooth, if we're in differentiable topology) or there is indeed no work involved at all. So find $\phi: \Bbb R^n \to [0,1]$ **continuous** so that

$$\phi(y)=\begin{cases} 0 & y \in B(x,r)\\
                1 & y \in B(x,R)^\complement \\
   \end{cases}$$

It's geometrically quite obvious what has to be done here: we only have to define $\phi(y)$ for $y$ with $r \le \|x-y\| < R$, as the rest is prescribed..